# Aligning SVG images created by jEuclid in XSL-FO

Tags: svg, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

As part of our PDF generation process, our team uses jEuclid to convert MathML equations to SVG images.

While we've successfully included them as external graphics, the inline equations themselves are not lining up with the surrounding text, being either too low or too high, depending on the image size.

Is there a way to define these SVG images in such a way that the equation baseline can be aligned with external text?

I've tried almost every combination of vertical-align and alignment-baseline.  The best I've come up with so far (vertical-align: mathematical) still requires a baseline shift of 3pts, and it's still not perfect.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
stroke-dasharray="none" shape-rendering="auto" font-family="'Dialog'" width="26" 
text-rendering="auto" fill-opacity="1"
contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" color-interpolation="auto" color-rendering="auto" 
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" font-size="12" fill="black" stroke="black" 
image-rendering="auto" stroke-miterlimit="10" zoomAndPan="magnify" version="1.0" 
stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="miter" contentStyleType="text/css" 
font-style="normal" height="13" stroke-width="1" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-weight="normal" 
stroke-opacity="1">
```

Comment: Is jEuclid sensible enough to put the origin of the coordinates within the SVG on the baseline of the first line of the rendered equation? (The images on the jEuclid website seem to all be PNG, so I can't tell.)  Is it possible for you to use a formatter that natively supports MathML?

Comment: There is no way in which you can align text content inside an SVG with external coordinate systems just with CSS. You will need to actively inspect the SVG (usually through its DOM interfaces). Even if you identify the user coordinate system, as suggested by @TonyGraham, you will need to find the [equivalent transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#ComputingAViewportsTransform) that connects it to the viewport coordinate system, for example through the [getScreenCTM](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/types.html#__svg__SVGGraphicsElement__getScreenCTM) API.

Comment: @TonyGraham I was using DocumentComposer, but that is no longer supported.

Comment: @ccprog I have access to the DOM of the SVG (I extract the height & width).  I'll check your links, thank you.

Comment: @TonyGraham

To answer your other question, no, it does not put the baseline anywhere I can determine.

Comment: Pity. If it had that, then you could have worked out the baseline shift to use to align its baseline to the alphabetic baseline using either XSLT or the DOM, as@ccprog suggested.

Comment: I'm looking at using MathJax instead of jEuclid.  Based on some online demos, it looks like it may include baseline info.